# Как сделать ZoomControl только в полноэкранном режиме?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как сделать элемент управления ZoomControl только в полноэкранном режиме?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прослушивайте события использования контрола fullscreenControl и переключайте видимость элемента управления zoomControl. Этого должно быть достаточно.

Вот пример рабочего кода:

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                center: [55.76, 37.64], // Москва
            zoom: 11,
            controls: []
            });

var fullscreenControl = new ymaps.control.FullscreenControl(),
        zoomControl = new ymaps.control.ZoomControl();

myMap.controls.add(fullscreenControl)
        .add(zoomControl);

zoomControl.options.set('visible', false);

fullscreenControl.events.add("fullscreenenter", function (e) {
zoomControl.options.set('visible', true);
});

fullscreenControl.events.add("fullscreenexit", function (e) {
zoomControl.options.set('visible', false);
});

}
```